# Playing a a song while program executes

Tags: python, audio, python-playsound

I'd like to know what code will allow me to play an audio track (mp3) while my game program executes. Once the song finishes I would like it to play over and over till the player is done with the game.

Answer (score 0):

#install pip then
import playsound

playsound.playsound('your?audio?file)

Comment: hey, it would be great to add a better explanation for the OP to understand.

Comment: This not very useful when implementing it just plays the sound and the code does not execute